# MySql query returning all the data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use checkbox to look into my DB but i don't know why, the answer is made of all the data of the table and not the specific entry I want!

Code

```
$req_lieux = $sqlQuery->query("select lieux.nom from lieux, type_lieu WHERE lieux.id_type_lieu = type_lieu.ID");
```

PHP code:

```
<fieldset>
            <legend class="title-color-bloc">Couleur</legend>
            <?php
            require_once 'search.php';
            /* la requête est dans search.php */
            while ($couleurs = $query_check_color->fetch())
            {?>
            <input class="color-choice" type="checkbox" id="color-choice<?php echo $couleurs['ID']; ?>" name="color-choice[]" value="<?php echo $couleurs['ID']; ?>">
            <label for="color-choice<?php echo $couleurs['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $couleurs['couleur']; ?></label>
            <?php
            }
            $query_check_color->closeCursor();
            ?>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="title-color-bloc">Lieux</legend>
            <?php
            /* la requête est dans search.php */
            while ($types = $query_check_types->fetch())
            {?>
                <input class="type-choice" type="checkbox" id="type-choice<?php echo $types['ID']; ?>" name="type-choice[]" value="<?php echo $types['ID']; ?>">
                <label for="type-choice<?php echo $types['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $types['libelle']; ?></label>
                <?php
            }
            $query_check_types->closeCursor();
            ?>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Afficher" class="submit-btn" name="submit-btn">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['type-choice']))
        {
            $type = implode("," , $_POST['type-choice']);
            while ($type = $req_lieux->fetch())
            { ?>
                <h1><?php echo $type['nom'] ?></h1>
            <?php }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You never pass your ID into the query, so you return all the lieux that have a  type_lieu, if you want a specific recore you should add " AND lieux.ID = YOUR_ID". Where YOUR_ID is the value of your checkbox.

Comment: `from lieux, type_lieu WHERE lieux.id_type_lieu = type_lieu.ID` is a INNER JOIN but you should not use the old JOIN syntax but the newer INNER JOIN ON syntax. "the answer is made of all the data of the table and not the specific entry I want! "  because you didn't filter out the record you need.

Comment: `$req_lieux = $sqlQuery->query("select lieux.nom from lieux INNER JOIN type_lieu ON lieux.id_type_lieu = type_lieu.ID");`  i still get all the result !

Comment: @MatthieuRigaux `$req_lieux = $sqlQuery->query("select lieux.nom from lieux INNER JOIN type_lieu ON lieux.id_type_lieu = type_lieu.ID WHERE type_lieu.id = YOUR_ID_GOES_HERE");` You have to filter the results of this join to get the record you want using a `WHERE` clause in your SQL statement. Probably want to use parameter binding through PDO or mysqli* functionality here too, but that's another subject.

Comment: `$req_lieux = $sqlQuery->query("select lieux.nom from lieux INNER JOIN type_lieu ON lieux.id_type_lieu = type_lieu.ID WHERE type_lieu.id = YOUR_ID_GOES_HERE");`  by 'YOUR_ID_GOES_HERE' you mean the value of the checkbox ? i don't get it sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not restricting the results of your query to any specific type.

```
select lieux.nom from lieux, type_lieu WHERE lieux.id_type_lieu = type_lieu.ID
```

This query will select every record from lieux where a record exists in type_lieu.

So if you have a specific type_lieu you're trying to use then you do something like the following:

```
SELECT l.nom from lieux AS l INNER JOIN type_lieu AS tl ON l.id_type_lieu = tl.ID WHERE tl.type = xxxx
```

Comment: `SELECT l.nom from lieux AS l INNER JOIN type_lieu AS tl ON l.id_type_lieu = tl.ID WHERE tl.type = xxxx`  sorry what is l.nom ?

Comment: Note that after the `FROM lieux`, I added `AS l`. This is called a table alias and allows you to use the alias `l` in your select and joins instead of having to write the table name in all parts of your query. `lieux.[column name]` becomes `l.[column name]`

[link] https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp [link]